# Taking values in a multi-dimensional array to make a brand new one consisting of keys and values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have this kind of array :

```
<?php

$arr = [    0 => [ ... ],

            1 => [  0 => 'one',
                    1 => 'two',
                    2 => 'three',
                    ...
                ],

            2 => [ ... ],

            3 => [  0 => 'guy',
                    1 => 'brush',
                    2 => 'threepwood',
                    ...
                ]
        ];
```

What could be the most reduced line of code to get :

```
$newArr = [
    'one' => 'guy',
    'two' => 'brush',
    'three' => 'threepwood',
    ...
];
```

**?**

`$arr[1]` and `$arr[3]` has the same number of elements of course.

Comment: raging people => it's not homework

Comment: so what about `$arr[0]` and `$arr[2]` ? do they matter at all?

Comment: @CodeGodie yeah, actually it's the array you get when you do a preg_match_all and the results into index 1 and 3 have some correlated meaning that I want to merge in an simple associative array !

Answer (score 1):

if `$arr[0]` and `$arr[2]` do not matter, then just iterate and place the first set's value as the second set's key as such:

```
foreach($arr[1] as $k => $v){
    $newArr[$v] = $arr[3][$k];
}

print_r($newArr);
```

or something like this:

```
$newArr = array_combine($arr[1], $arr[3]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I can go with that but I was more thinking about some combinations of the native array methods without making a foreach, no idea ?